# webpack-remove-empty-scripts is removing asset.php files

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, sass, node-modules

I am using Webpack 5 with this plugin: https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts

The build process is running @WordPress/Scripts. This will also output an asset.php file for each CSS file generated.

I want to use that plugin to remove the .JS files that get created with the compiled CSS files. These .JS files are empty and just annoying to have in there.

When using the plugin it is also removing my asset.php files as well. I have tried the options including ignoring asset.php files but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas? Below is the code I have:

```
const otherStyleConfig = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        'blog': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'blog.scss' ),
        'editor': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'editor.scss' ),
        'header-footer': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'header-footer.scss' ),
        'partners': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'partners.scss' ),
        'posts-and-pages': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'posts-and-pages.scss' ),
        'resource-center': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'resource-center.scss' ),
        'resource-single': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'resource-single.scss' ),
        'support-center': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'support-center.scss' ),
        'table-of-contents': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'table-of-contents.scss' ),
        'widgets': path.resolve( './src/sass', 'widgets.scss' ),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        url: false, //Don't do anything with image url's
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                sortMediaQueries(),
                                presetEnv(),
                                mergeLonghand(),
                                mergeRules(),
                                cssnano( {
                                    reduceIdents: false,
                                    zindex: false,
                                    autoprefixer: false,
                                } ),
                            ],
                            options: {},
                        },
                     },
                },
                'resolve-url-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ],
        },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/css'),
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new DependencyExtractionWebpackPlugin(),
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin({
            verbose: true,
            ignore: [
                /.*asset.php$/,
            ]
        }),
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in the [webpack-remove-empty-scripts](https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts) v0.8.4 and later.